# Wrong results from frequency counting

Tags: python

I am trying to find the occurences of one list of words in another list of words.
My code looks like this:

```
for cat, text2 in posts:
words=wordpunct_tokenize(text2)
for word in words:
    if word in top:
        counter[word]+=1

print counter
```

Words looks like this: `[("Post1", "post1" ,"post1"), ("post2","post2), ("post3")]`
top looks like this `"Post1, Post2, Post3"`
An expected result would be:

```
{post1: 3}
{post2, 2}
{post3, 1}
```

however the output I now get is:

```
{'post1': 3})
{'post2': 2, 'post1': 3})
{'post3': 1, 'post2': 2, 'post1': 3})
```

It looks like the program adds the words from the previous line to the next one, anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure about the indentation? Is counter outside the loop?

Comment: You are correct, "print counter" ought to be inside the loop this seems to be lost when pasting it here.

Comment: @NipunBatra I second. @Nikolaas I think the code is doing what you tell it to. Where do you initialize `counter`? Since `counter` is updated for each entry in `posts`, it needs to be reinitialized within the same loop (i.e. the loop `for ... in posts:`); otherwise, the modifications from the previous loop iteration will be kept for the next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint: there's a class in Python that already does what you want, it's called [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and it's in the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for cat, text2 in posts:
    c.update(word for word in wordpunct_tokenize(text2) if word in top)
```

At the end, the `c` variable will contain the frequency count of the words found.

Comment: The problem with this is that it counts all the occurences of any words in the posts, I need it to only count words that are in top.
Thanks a million for looking at it though!

Comment: Thanks a million that was great.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing though. 
Say I take all the values, thus values=c.values(). and I want to convert them to relative frequencies.
I would write: rel=values/len(words)
However values is a list of floats not floats, how would I fix this?

Comment: Like this? `[x/float(len(c)) for x in c.values()]`

Comment: If I try this, I get the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: That's because you're trying to divide a _number_ with a _list_, you must divide a number with a number, and for that you need to divide each of the numbers in the list, not the list itself